# Listing or bundling all needed dependencies of a Jar file. How?

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

I'm currently working with a .jar file that needs other .jar files to work correctly. The problem is that some of that jar dependencies will depend yet in other jar dependencies. The game goes on.

I'm in look for a tool that would allow me either give the original jar file and the set of possible jar files / folders where the dependencies must be and have it tell me which ones are needed OR a tool that would bundle them all together.

The first option would be the preferred one, although the second one would be alright, too.

What's the simplest way to accomplish this task? (This isn't a maven project).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Apache Maven`, you can use the [`Shade`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or [`OneJar`](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) plugin to accomplish that. You can also use [`onejar`](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) with `Apache Ant`.

Comment: As stated above: This isn't a maven project and I'm not really familiar with it.

Comment: I didn't notice in time :) I'll leave this here for future reference